# reverse proxy to external url with rewrite

Tags: nginx

I am creating an application and I would like to do the following redirection  http://myapp.com/4/45/abc =>  https://example.com/id=4&p=45&name=abc.
To do this I tried the following

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.com;

    location ~ ^/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z]*)$ {

    proxy_pass https://example.com/id=$1&p=$2&name=$3;
    
   }
```

But without result because it gives me an error

Comment: Don't add tags that are irrelevant to the question. Remove 'CSS'

Comment: What is the error? Please share more details like error and access.log

Comment: i am working on localhost:    server_name localhost;

Comment: [error] 4708#7672: *1 no resolver defined to resolve example.com, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"